# Creating a hyperlink using Google Maps API Static Map and Excel

Tags: excel, url, hyperlink, google-api

I am trying to create a hyperlink URL that would allow me to use the lat,long coordinates from an excel spreadsheet. Given some data in the spreadsheet, a cell (ie. A2) populates the coordinates in lat,long form. The coordinates in this cell are always random. I have found the correct hyperlink format for a SINGLE point as follows, which is included in the excel cell if data is available:

If data is available on A1, open up hyperlink with marker onto static map:

=IF(A1=" ",HYPERLINK("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap center=22.071046,-159.529477&zoom=10&size=400x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:1C"&A1,"Click here to view"))

I want to be able to do this same functionality for MULTIPLE markers/data. For example, if A1 and B1 both have data, I want to populate both markers on the same static map.

What would be the hyperlink format to achieve this? I keep running into syntax errors, or the map doesn't populate with markers at all.

Please and thank you,

Brandon